Initialization of a secure server in OPCUA using Open62541
I am trying to create a minimal server using ACS and AES256 certificates.
Code and certificates
I've build the certificates using OpenSSL.



Step
Command
Result




Server Private Key
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out opcua_server.key -aes256
Encrypted key


Server Signing Request
openssl req -new -key opcua_server.key -out request.csr
CSR Request


Server Certificate with URI
openssl req -new -key decrypted_opcua_server.key -x509 -days 365 -out certificate.pem -subj "/C=IT/ST=Campania/L=Roma/O=Senatus Romanum/CN=Opcua Legionis" -addext "subjectAltName=URI:urn:OPCUASecureServerTest"
PEM Certificate


Decapsulate to DER
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -outform der -out certificate.der
DER Certificate


Certificate Data Display
openssl x509 -in certificate.der -inform der -text -noout
None



I then attempt to setup the server.
Utilities
UA_StatusCode myInsecurePasswordCallback(UA_ServerConfig *sc,
                                                UA_ByteString *bytestringPassword) {
    char* sec = (char*)"insecure_password";
    *bytestringPassword = UA_STRING_ALLOC(sec);
    return UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD;
}

void printApplicationUriFromLoadedCertificate(UA_ServerConfig *config) {
    UA_Boolean none = false;
    printf("Verifying certificates on endpoints...\n");
    // Loop through the existing security policies and print certificate info
    for(size_t i = 0; i < config->securityPoliciesSize; i++) {
        UA_EndpointDescription *endpoint = &config->endpoints[0];
        UA_ByteString *certificate = &endpoint->serverCertificate;
        printf("*");
        if(certificate->length > 0) {
            printf("\nLoaded Certificate Application URI: %.*s\n", (int)certificate->length, certificate->data);
            none = true;
        }
    }
    if (!none) printf("\nNo certificate loaded.\n");
}

// Custom permissions and roles functions
UA_UInt32 custom_getUserPermissions(const UA_AccessControl *ac, void *sessionContext, const UA_NodeId *nodeId, UA_UInt32 permissions) {
    return permissions;
}

static UA_Boolean
allowAddNode(UA_Server *server, UA_AccessControl *ac,
             const UA_NodeId *sessionId, void *sessionContext,
             const UA_AddNodesItem *item) {
    printf("Called allowAddNode\n");
    return UA_TRUE;
}

static UA_Boolean
allowAddReference(UA_Server *server, UA_AccessControl *ac,
                  const UA_NodeId *sessionId, void *sessionContext,
                  const UA_AddReferencesItem *item) {
    printf("Called allowAddReference\n");
    return UA_TRUE;
}

static UA_Boolean
allowDeleteNode(UA_Server *server, UA_AccessControl *ac,
                const UA_NodeId *sessionId, void *sessionContext,
                const UA_DeleteNodesItem *item) {
    printf("Called allowDeleteNode\n");
    return UA_FALSE; // Do not allow deletion from client
}

static UA_Boolean
allowDeleteReference(UA_Server *server, UA_AccessControl *ac,
                     const UA_NodeId *sessionId, void *sessionContext,
                     const UA_DeleteReferencesItem *item) {
    printf("Called allowDeleteReference\n");
    return UA_TRUE;
}

static UA_UsernamePasswordLogin userNamePW[2] = {
    {UA_STRING_STATIC("station-client"), UA_STRING_STATIC("operator1")},
    {UA_STRING_STATIC("admin-client"), UA_STRING_STATIC("superSecurePassword1!")}
};

Server
int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, stopHandler);
    signal(SIGTERM, stopHandler);

    UA_String applicationUri =  UA_String_fromChars("urn:open62541.OPCUASecureServerTest");

    // Hardcoded paths to the certificate and private key files
    const char* certificatePath =  "./modules/opcua/src/.server_security/certificate.der";
    const char* privateKeyPath =  "./modules/opcua/src/.server_security/privatekey.der";

    // Load server certificates
    const UA_ByteString certificate = loadFile(certificatePath);
    const UA_ByteString privateKey = loadFile(privateKeyPath);

    // Create the server
    UA_Server *server = UA_Server_new();
    UA_ServerConfig *config = UA_Server_getConfig(server);
    
    // Output the Application URI for debugging
    std::cout << "############\n## " << "Application URI: " << std::string((char*)config->applicationDescription.applicationUri.data, applicationUri.length) << "\n############\n" << std::endl;
    UA_StatusCode retval;
    UA_UInt16 portNumber = 4840;
    UA_ByteString trustList[] = { certificate };
    size_t trustListSize = sizeof(trustList) / sizeof(UA_ByteString);
    const UA_ByteString *issuerList = {};
    size_t issuerListSize = 0;
    const UA_ByteString *revocationList = {};
    size_t revocationListSize = 0;

    /// option to start the server without None auth enabled.
    retval = UA_ServerConfig_setDefaultWithSecureSecurityPolicies(
      config, portNumber, 
      &certificate, &privateKey,
      trustList, trustListSize,
      issuerList, issuerListSize, 
      revocationList, revocationListSize);
    config->privateKeyPasswordCallback = myInsecurePasswordCallback;
    config->applicationDescription.applicationUri = applicationUri;
    config->applicationDescription.applicationName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT_ALLOC("en-US", "Secure Monkey Server");
    /* Override accessControl functions for nodeManagement */
    config->accessControl.allowAddNode = allowAddNode;
    config->accessControl.allowAddReference = allowAddReference;
    config->accessControl.allowDeleteNode = allowDeleteNode;
    config->accessControl.allowDeleteReference = allowDeleteReference;
    UA_ServerConfig_addSecurityPolicyBasic256Sha256(config, &certificate, &privateKey);

    // Output the Application URI for debugging
    std::cout << "Application URI: " << std::string((char*)config->applicationDescription.applicationUri.data, applicationUri.length) << std::endl;

    // Print the Application URI from the certificate after it has been loaded
    printApplicationUriFromLoadedCertificate(config);

    // [AUDITING](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part4/v104/docs/6.5)
    if(retval != UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD)
        goto cleanup;

    if(!running)
        goto cleanup; // received ctrl-c already

    retval = UA_Server_run(server, &running);

 cleanup:
    UA_ByteString_clear((UA_ByteString*)&certificate);
    UA_ByteString_clear((UA_ByteString*)&privateKey);

    UA_Server_delete(server);
    return retval == UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}

Output
I have edited this slightly for readability.
[2024-09-27 10:05:45.864 (UTC+0200)] warn/server         AccessControl: Unconfigured AccessControl. Users have all permissions.

[2024-09-27 10:05:45.865 (UTC+0200)] info/server

AccessControl: Anonymous login is enabled 

[2024-09-27 10:05:45.866 (UTC+0200)] warn/server      x509 Certificate Authentication configured, but no encrypting SecurityPolicy. This can leak credentials on the network.

############
## Application URI: urn:open62541.server.application²²²
############

[2024-09-27 10:05:46.043 (UTC+0200)] warn/userland      ServerUrls already set. Overriding. 

[2024-09-27 10:05:46.047 (UTC+0200)] warn/server        AccessControl: Unconfigured AccessControl. Users have all permissions.     

[2024-09-27 10:05:46.047 (UTC+0200)] warn/server        x509 Certificate Authentication configured, but no encrypting SecurityPolicy. This can leak credentials on the network.


Application URI: urn:open62541.OPCUASecureServerTest Verifying certificates on endpoints...

***** No certificate loaded. 

[2024-09-27 10:05:46.048 (UTC+0200)] warn/server        The certificate's application URI could not be verified. StatusCode BadCertificateUriInvalid 

[2024-09-27 10:05:46.048 (UTC+0200)] warn/server        The certificate's application URI could not be verified. StatusCode BadCertificateUriInvalid 

[2024-09-27 10:05:46.048 (UTC+0200)] warn/server        The certificate's application URI could not be verified. StatusCode BadCertificateUtificateUriInvalid 

[2024-09-27 10:05:46.048 (UTC+0200)] warn/server        The certificate's application URI could not be verified. StatusCode BadCertificateUriInvalid

Questions
1- Is my assumption that I should start with a new server, using UA_Server_new then set it up with default secure policies using the UA_ServerConfig_setDefaultWithSecureSecurityPolicies method, then rely on UA_ServerConfig_addSecurityPolicyBasic256Sha256 to set the certificate, awfully incorrect? The many warnings seem to suggest I'm doing something wrong.
2- Why is my certificate not working? Did I fail in the creation step, in the import state, or both?
3- Is my ACS correct or not? I used the project example as a source.

I am not sure about other parts of your question, but you certainly also need the hostname(s) or IP address(es) of the server in the subjectAltName. See https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part6/v104/docs/6.2.2 .
